# Como mostrar um UIAlertView quando um link é acionado no UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, link

Cenário do problema:

Existe um link em um `UITextView`, quando este link é disparado ele deverá abrir uma página web. Esta parte já está funcionando.
 Porém preciso mostrar um `UIAlertView` perguntando se realmente deseja abrir o link no navegador. Em caso "OK", permitir que a operação continue, em caso de "Cancelar", encerrar a abertura da página web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemente o método `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange;` do delegate de UITextView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 50)];
    textView.text = @"http://www.google.com.br";
    textView.editable = NO;
    textView.selectable = YES;
    [textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
    textView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {

    url = URL;
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aviso"
                                                        message:@"Deseja abrir o link?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertView show];
    return NO;
}
```

Nesse método você cria o alert view e retorna NO, para não deixar o sistema interagir com a URL (nesse caso abri-la no navegador).
Agora implemente o delegate de UIAlertView para receber os eventos de click nos botões e abra a URL:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito boa a explicação!! Funcionou!! Obrigado @RafaelLeão